# Celery sometimes do not create tasks

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue, celery, message

I am developing a Python API that uses Celery with Redis and RabbitMQ in order to manage my messages. Sometimes, when I submit some tasks to the queue, it just will not receive the messages I was expecting, it keeps empty, and when a retry them manually they may run. The messages that it misses are usually the same, but I can not understand why some specific arguments will only work sometimes.

I have tried many codes to submit the messages.
The first one:

```
advertising_price_set_item.delay(account_id=account.id, tool_id=tool_id,
                                         ml_item_id=advertising.external_id,
                                         price=price, process_id=process_id)
```

The second one:

```
advertising_price_set_item.apply_async(kwargs={'account_id': account.id, 'tool_id': tool_id,
                                               'ml_item_id': advertising.external_id,
                                               'price': price, 'process_id': process_id}, retry=True)
```

And finally:

```
try:
    advertising_price_set_item.apply_async(kwargs={'account_id': account.id, 'tool_id': tool_id,
                                                   'ml_item_id': advertising.external_id,
                                                   'price': price, 'process_id': process_id}, retry=True,
                                           retry_policy={'max_retries': 44,
                                                         'interval_start': 0,
                                                         'interval_step': 0.2,
                                                         'interval_max': 0.2},)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

But all of them failed at some point, and I never got any message of Exception or error.

The message in RabbitMQ looks something like this:

```
{'user_id': 1, 'tool_id': 1, 'ml_items_id': ['A123', 'B123', 'C123'], 'price_premium': 0.01, 'price_classic': 0.01, 'price_free': 0.01, 'process_id': 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find an answer why sometimes messages would disappear between Celery and RabbitMQ, but at least I found out that changing my broker to Redis solved my problem!

If your having difficulties with messages being lost or not sent to RabbitMQ try to change your broker to Redis.